# Do Flex & Flash supported on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, flash, apache-flex, mobile-application

I am a Flex developer. I wish to make flex applications for iphone.

But, when I google up for the same, most of the link shows up that Adobe Flex and flash aren't supported on iphone.

1. Is this right ? Why it isn't supported ?
2. If it is supported, which are the good books for developing iphone applications via flex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Adobe air is supported on iOS devices now with Flex 4.5.1 - as a flex developer, you CAN develop applications to be installed on iOS as well as Android and Blackberry playbook (at this time)

See here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios_features_in_air26.html

Comment: To Clarify, you can write an app in flex, targeting the iOS AIR platform.  Flex is an SDK and framework to build flash applications.  Air and Flash Player are just platforms and api extensions by which you can run those applications. Therefore, YES, you can run an app on the iOS AIR platform, that you develop with Flex - You can also run an AIR app that you develop with Flash CS5.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Support and performance for AS3 based projects on iOS is limited.

If you are a Flex developer, you will feel right at home building iOS apps using Objective-C and the native CocoaTouch frameworks.

Check out the Winter 2010 Stanford University "Developing Apps for iOS" course on iTunesU. The sessions are free and provide a very easy to understand way to get up and running in just a few hours.

Comment: The latest numbers indicate over 222 million iOS devices on the market. There are nowhere near that many Android devices with Flash support (Android devices [total 100m to date](http://www.droiddog.com/android-blog/2011/05/google-releases-new-android-sales-numbers-100-million-devices-activated-to-date/), only a subset of which support Flash) in circulation. For the moment, if you're developing commercially for mobile, you're developing for iOS. All I'm saying is that migrating to native iOS development from AS3 is relatively straightforward and provides a significant long term advantage.